# How to retrieve users wishlist with product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am writing an REST API in magento to retrieve the user's wishlist with product details. The below code written the null result. can anyone suggest what is the issue ?

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

if (count($wishListItemCollection)) 
{
$arrProductIds = array();

foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
    $arrProductIds = array();

    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a little explanation to your code. Code only answers are not appreciated.